# undefined variable error in csh script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have one function in csh script and in this function I am using one variable which is sourced from one file. But while using script its throwing undefined error for same variable.
I am using Linux.

My Code

```
function init_remote_commands_to_use
{
    # Test if the environment variable SSH_FOR_RCOMMANDS is present in .temip_config file,
    # use secured on non secured rcommand depending on the result

    if [  "$SSH_FOR_RCOMMANDS" != "" ]
    then
        if [ "$SSH_FOR_RCOMMANDS" = "ON" ]
        then
            # Check if the environment variable SSH_PATH is specified in .temip_config file
            if  [ "$SSH_PATH" != "" ]
            then
                SH_RCMD=$SSH_PATH
            else
                SH_RCMD=$SSH_CMD
            fi
            # Check if a ssh-agent is already running
            if [ "$SSH_AGENT_PID" = "" ]
            then
                #Run ssh-agent for secured RCommands
                eval `ssh-agent`
                ssh-add
                STARTEDBYME=YES
            fi

        else
            if [ "$SSH_FOR_RCOMMANDS" = "OFF" ]
            then
                SH_RCMD=$RSH_CMD
            else
                echo "Please set the SSH_FOR_RCOMMANDS value to ON or OFF in the .temip_config file"
                exit 1
            fi
        fi
    else
        SH_RCMD=$RSH_CMD

    fi
}
```

below is the error:

```
function: Command not found.
{: Command not found.
SSH_FOR_RCOMMANDS: Undefined variable.
```

Please anyone suggest what I am missing?

Comment: Add your code along with this error

Comment: This is not a csh script...? This looks like `bash` (not `sh`) ... Perhaps try executing it with `bash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C Shell `csh` does not have functions.  It does have aliases, but those are harder to write and read.  For exmaple, see here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62032/error-converting-a-bash-function-to-a-csh-alias

It might be a good idea to simply switch to Bash, where your existing code may already be working.

Comment: can you pls tell me how to use above code in  aliases in csh?

Comment: You would have to just string it all together as one giant string.  It will be disgusting.  You could instead put it in a file by itself and invoke it as a program.

Comment: It's not just the functions; the above script doesn't even remotely resemble a csh script: wrong syntax for `if` (correct: `if ( .. ) then endif`) and you assign variables with `set` (correct: `set var = value`, or `setenv var = value` for environment variables) ...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: correct.  If you move the whole thing to a file, it would be a bash script, not a csh one.  It would still be invokable from csh.

Comment: how to source a file from csh script?

Comment: You don't "source" it, you "invoke" it with something like `bash thefile.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

The C Shell lacks a function feature. Aliases may serve as workaround, but are somewhat painful to work with. A better workaround is to use `goto` and `source`:

```
alias function 'set argv = ( _FUNC \!* ) ; source $0'

if ( "$1" == "_FUNC" ) goto "$2"

set str = "`function myfunc`"
set ret = "$status"
echo "$str"
if ( "$ret" < 0 ) exit -1
exit

myfunc:
set ret = 0
if ( "$SSH_FOR_RCOMMANDS" != "" ) then
  if ( "$SSH_FOR_RCOMMANDS" == "ON" ) then
    # Check if the environment variable SSH_PATH is specified in .temip_config file.
    if ( "$SSH_PATH" != "" ) then
      echo "$SSH_PATH"
    else
      echo "$SSH_CMD"
    endif
    # Check if a ssh-agent is already running.
    if ( "$SSH_AGENT_PID" == "" ) then
      # Run ssh-agent for secured RCommands.
      eval "`ssh-agent`"
      ssh-add
      echo YES
    endif
  else
    if ( "$SSH_FOR_RCOMMANDS" == "OFF" ) then
      echo "$RSH_CMD"
    else
      echo "Please, set the SSH_FOR_RCOMMANDS value to ON or OFF in the .temip_config file."
      set ret = 1
    endif
  endif
else
  echo "$RSH_CMD"
endif
exit "$ret"
```