# how to check existence of any file in csh script?

Tags: linux, csh

For checking the existence of any file in csh script I am using

```
if [ -f /var/opt/temip/conf/.temip_config ]
```

but I am getting below error

```
if [ -f /var/opt/temip/conf/.temip_config ]

if: Expression Syntax.
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: That is not valid Csh syntax at all.

Which is a good thing, because you should probably not be doing your scripting in Csh.

Your syntax is fine for `sh` which is probably what you should be using anyway.  Without the context of the rest of your script, we can't really tell whether changing the first line to `#!/bin/sh` would be feasible, though.

Comment: @tripleee can you pls simply tell me how to check file existence in csh script?

Comment: Give up `csh`. Code your script in POSIX sh (for portability), or in GNU `bash` or in Python or in `zsh`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [the manpage](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/File_inquiry_operators.html):

```
f
    Plain file
```

You use it with a `if` statement:

```
if ( -f file.txt ) then
    echo Exists
else
    echo No such file
endif
```

Based on this question [and your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27813432/undefined-variable-error-in-csh-script), you seem to be rather clueless as to how `csh` syntax works, since you keep using POSIX shell syntax. I would **strongly** suggest that you either familiarise yourself with the `csh` syntax, or just use a POSIX shell (which is probably better for scripting anyway).

Answer (score 15):

In CShell for checking of the existence of a file use `-e` option

The name of the file does not have to be "hard coded" into the if statement, but
may be a parameter like this:

```
 if (-e "$filePath") then
```

Here is a full list of the Cshell file queries.

```
-e file           file merely exists (may be protected from user)
-r file           file exists and is readable by user
-w file           file is writable by user
-x file           file is executable by user
-o file           file is owned by user
-z file           file has size 0
-f file           file is an ordinary file
-d file           file is a directory
```